# Selenium not deleting profiles created under Temp folder on CentOS

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, centos

I am running my Selenium test on CentOS for some time now and lately I encountered a lot of stability issues and crashes for my test runs. I went on to find that Selenium browser profiles created under the `temp` folder were never getting deleted. I manually deleted all temp files and now the system seems stable. Is there a check I can put in place to handle this and ensure temp files are deleted once the browser instance is terminated by `driver.quit()`?

Comment: Have you solve this problem. I am facing the same

Comment: I have implemented a workaround. Please see answers section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a permanent fix for this but here is a workaround I implemented to clean the temp directories created by my browser(chrome)

```
#!/bin/bash

#file that has a list of all server IPs that need the temp folder cleaned
server_lists=/etc/server_lists

#command to clean temp with chromium directories created prior to 30 minutes
cmd='echo "Clean temp"; find  /tmp/ -maxdepth 1  -mmin +30 -iname ".org.chromium*" -type d  -exec rm -rf "{}" \; && echo Done'

for ip in $( < $server_lists )
do

   ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $ip "$cmd" 

done
```

I run this shell script every 30 minutes to check and clean all temp directories created by my browser

Comment: but does it checked whether that profile is in use or not?. Its like in my case all the users will start the execution so don't have any idea how many browsers are used at that time and how many profiles i need to delete.

Comment: I am assuming each of your test case(individual test cases) will take no longer than 15-20 minutes(on the higher side). If you believe your test cases will take more time, I would suggest you increase the -mmin variable from +30 to +60. This should delete all profile created prior to 60 minutes from current time.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete all cookies before quitting the driver. That should do it.

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

That's all you could do for wiping data before quitting the driver.

Comment: This would delete all the cookies associated with the webdriver instance, however, the profile created for the instance still remains.

Comment: This is all Selenium provides as for wiping data. If this doesn't help then I'm afraid there's nothing in Selenium able to help you.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the temp file created by the instance in a File variable and later create a check to delete it after driver.quit? I could check if the File exist and delete it? thoughts?

Comment: If you know the path to where the tmp files are kept you can indeed store it in a file variable and that way delete it manually after quitting the driver.

Comment: The problem with that approach is I cannot delete all files in the temp folder. There may me a few instances on webdriver running when instance 1 exists. So I need to way to find out the file/folder created by a webdriver instance inside temp folder

Comment: That's a problem, as that is just not possible with Selenium.